# linux printing remotely with lp command to cups server not working

Tags: linux, printing, docker, network-printer, cups

I want to print between docker compose containers. There are two containers to the issue:

- cups: cups daemon
- php-apache: print with lp

### cups container:

print locally, example

```bsh
$ lp -d developer-epson-alm320dn -h cups:631 -n 1 sample.pdf
request id is developer-epson-alm320dn-6 (1 file(s))
```

head of cupsd.conf

```
LogLevel warn
PageLogFormat
MaxLogSize 0
ErrorPolicy retry-job
ServerName *
# Allow remote access
Port 631
Listen /run/cups/cups.sock
# Share local printers on the local network.
Browsing On
BrowseLocalProtocols dnssd
DefaultAuthType Basic
WebInterface Yes
DefaultEncryption IfRequested
<Location />
  # Allow shared printing and remote administration...
  Order allow,deny
  Allow all
</Location>
# ...
```

### php-apache container

```bsh
$ lp -d developer-epson-alm320dn -h cups:631 -n 1 /tmp/print-KflCQR.pdf
lp: Error - The printer or class does not exist.
```

```bsh
$ ping cups
PING cups (172.18.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from mssystem-cups.docker_default (172.18.0.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.082 ms
```

```bsh
$ curl cups:631/printers/developer-epson-alm320dn | grep SUMMARY
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0<TABLE SUMMARY="developer-epson-alm320dn">
100  4650    0  4650    0     0   756k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  756k
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  solved the problem:

```
#... install cups-client and:
RUN mkdir -p /etc/cups && echo "ServerName cups" >  /etc/cups/client.conf
#...
```

After the print command works fine:

```bsh
$ lp -d developer-epson-alm320dn -n 1 sample.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it worked for me by reversing the parameters and not having to create and/or add a line to client.conf.

So the command in your question can be run like this, put the host argument first!

`lp -h cups:631 -d developer-epson-alm320dn -n 1 sample.pdf`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).